# Is there any way to get unique random sub arrays form array, each random array shouldn't has same element?

Tags: javascript, css

I need to show team members on the website. The site should show four team member profiles at a time. Since the team members are more than four, it should display team members randomly. A team member image should not repeat unless all other items have been shown at least once.

I was stuck at `pickRandomMembers`. Here `if (displayedArrayStore.length <= 4)` has to be false for second call but is true. If someone finds a solution, help me. And while executing members are adding to the existing ones but members have to replace.

Thanks

I have generated an array with random elements then displayed member cards with this array the first time

Next, I have stored that unique array for comparing with the next generated random unique array, but I am failing at comparing.

```js
I have generated an Array with random elements then displayed member cards 
window.onload = function () {
                let container = document.querySelector('.container');

                const memsToDisplay = 4,
                    path = 'assets/images/',
                    /* we can get data form API call and store data as follows, intsead i am taking my own */
                    teamMembers = [
                        {
                            memId: 101,
                            avathar: 'avathar.png',
                            memName: 'Srinivas ',
                            activities: 'Learn something NEW',
                        },
                        {
                            memId: 102,
                            avathar: 'avathar.png',
                            memName: 'Kevin Powell',
                            activities: 'Teaches CSS',
                        },
                        {
                            memId: 103,
                            avathar: 'avathar.png',
                            memName: 'Kyle Simpson',
                            activities: 'Teaches JS',
                        },
                        {
                            memId: 104,
                            avathar: 'avathar.png',
                            memName: 'Brendan Hufford',
                            activities: 'Teaches SEO',
                        },
                        {
                            memId: 105,
                            avathar: 'avathar.png',
                            memName: 'Gary Simon',
                            activities: 'Teaches Designing',
                        },
                        {
                            memId: 106,
                            avathar: 'avathar.png',
                            memName: 'Zell Leiw',
                            activities: 'Teaches JS',
                        },
                        {
                            memId: 107,
                            avathar: 'avathar.png',
                            memName: 'DEV ED',
                            activities: 'Teaches WEB',
                        },
                        {
                            memId: 108,
                            avathar: 'avathar.png',
                            memName: 'Eddie',
                            activities: 'Teaches Math',
                        },
                    ];

                let displayedArrayStore = [],
                    finalRandomArray = [],
                    isMoreThanFourUsers = false;

                /* Team member Card Making */
                function makingMemberCard(memsArrayUniuqe) {
                    console.log(memsArrayUniuqe);
                    memsArrayUniuqe.map((member, index) => {
                        
                        const card = document.createElement('div');
                        const image = document.createElement('img');
                        const name = document.createElement('p');
                        const desc = document.createElement('p');

                        /* Assigning class names */
                        card.classList.add('memberCard');
                        image.classList.add('avathar');
                        name.classList.add('memName');
                        desc.classList.add('activity');

                        /* Assigning data to it */
                        image.setAttribute(
                            'src',
                            `${path.concat(teamMembers[member].avathar)}`
                        );
                        name.innerText = ` ${teamMembers[member].memId} - ${teamMembers[member].memName}`;
                        desc.innerText = teamMembers[member].activities;

                        /* Appending to parent elements*/
                        container.append(card);
                        card.append(image);
                        card.append(name);
                        card.append(desc);
                    });
                }
                /* Removing Data with clearInterval */
                function removingMembers() {
                    let container = document.querySelector('.container');
                    container.remove();
                }
                /* Generating Random Numbers */
                function generatingRandomNumbers(members, memsToDisplay) {
                    console.log('generating');
                    let randomCheckArray;
                    if (members.length > memsToDisplay) {
                        randomCheckArray = new Set();
                        while (randomCheckArray.size !== 4) {
                            randomCheckArray.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * members.length));
                        }
                        finalRandomArray = Array.from(randomCheckArray);
                        return finalRandomArray;
                    } else {
                        finalRandomArray = members;
                    }
                    randomCheckArray = null;
                }
                function pickRandomMembers(members, memsToDisplay = 4) {
                    let teamMembersCopy = JSON.stringify(members);
                    let randomNumberArray = generatingRandomNumbers(
                        members,
                        memsToDisplay
                    );
                    if (members.length < 4) {
                        makingMemberCard(members);
                        cosnole.log('line 220');
                    } else {
                        if (displayedArrayStore.length <= 4) {
                            console.log('if pick');

                            //displayedArrayStore = [...randomNumberArray];
                            console.log(displayedArrayStore);
                            setInterval(
                                () =>
                                    makingMemberCard(
                                        generatingRandomNumbers(members, memsToDisplay)
                                    ),
                                5000
                            );

                            //makingMemberCard(generatingRandomNumbers(members, memsToDisplay));
                            //generatingRandomNumbers(members, memsToDisplay);
                            console.log('if after');
                        } else {
                            console.log('else pick');
                            displayedArrayStore = [...randomNumberArray];
                            for (let i = 0; i < randomNumberArray.length; i++) {
                                if (displayedArrayStore.indexOf(randomNumberArray[i]) === -1) {
                                    setInterval(makingMemberCard(randomNumberArray), 5000);
                                    //clearInterval(removingMembers(), 5000);
                                } else {
                                    generatingRandomNumbers(members, memsToDisplay);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                pickRandomMembers(teamMembers, memsToDisplay);
            };
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');

            :root {
                --primary-clr: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
                --secondary-clr: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

                --fontFamily: 'roboto', sans-serif;

                --fontSize: 16px;
            }

            *,
            ::after,
            ::before {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                background-color: var(--primary-clr) !important;
            }

            .container {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                height: auto;
                padding: 80px;
                gap: 20px;
            }
            .memberCard {
                flex: 1 1 20%;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                flex-direction: column;
                background-color: var(--secondary-clr);
                color: var(--primary-clr);
                font-family: var(--fontFamily);
                padding: 20px;
                border-radius: 1em;
            }

            .avathar {
                margin: 20px 0;
            }
            .memName {
                font-size: calc(var(--fontSize) + 2);
                margin: 10px 0;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            .activity {
                font-size: var(--font-size);
                margin: 10px 0;
            }

            @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
                .container {
                    flex-direction: row;
                    flex-wrap: wrap;
                    padding: 20px;
                    gap: 20px;
                }
                .memberCard {
                    flex: 1 1 48%;
                }
            }
            @media (max-width: 767px) {
                .container {
                    flex-direction: column;
                    padding: 20px;
                }
                .memberCard {
                    flex: none;
                }
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>My Site</title>
    
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Next time please write a title that actually describes the problem. Not one that tells you have a problem. Everyone has a problem, that's why they are here.

Comment: As a starter, I am confused about asking a question, but from next time onwards will focus on a question and won't repeat it. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a random-selector function like this:

```js
function getRandom(arr, x) {
  const copy = arr.slice(0);
  const selected = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
        
    const item = copy.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0];
    selected.push(item);
  }
  
  return selected;
}

const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

test.onclick = () => {
  const selected = getRandom(items, 4);
  console.log(selected.join(' '));
}
```

```html
<button id=test>Test</button>
```

Having a function like this, you can do whatever you want with the `selected` array.

Also, give a look at the docs of [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).